# Using if / else if need to populate nick names in R

Tags: r

I wanted to see nick names against name column

i have created vector (char), latter converted to data.frames. Now i want to see nick names against each names

```
 y = c("Varun","Rivan","Jyothi","others")
  y = data.frame(y)
  y$nicknames = ""
  View(y)


   y$nicknames = ifelse(y$y =="Varun","Vast",(ifelse(y$y =="Jyothi","jo", 
 (ifelse(y$y =="Rivan","Kidoo","others")))))
```

it is working for me, however need to see simple easy way to execute

Need to see nick names in different column

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when) from the `dplyr` library:

```
y$nicknames <- case_when(
    y$y == "Varun" ~ "Vast",
    y$y == "Jyothi" ~ "jo",
    y$y == "Rivan" ~ "Kidoo",
    TRUE ~ "others"
)
```